# Need help filtering a matrix based on a criterion in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm new to R so I ask for your help. Say I have the following matrix.

```
mat <- matrix(c(2,4,2,8, 1,4,11,9), 4)
dimnames(mat)[[2]] <- c("x", "y")
dimnames(mat)[[1]] <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
mat
  x y
a 2 1
b 4 4
c 2 11
d 8 9
```

I want to basically filter the matrix so that the new matrix only contains rows that only have an average value of 5 or higher. So in "mat", rows "a" and "b" would not meet this criteria and be deleted, and the new matrix would be as shown below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
mat
  x y
c 2 11
d 8 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mat[ rowMeans(mat) < 5 , ]   # rowMeans is much faster than the apply method
```

Answer (score 2):

For the original question, you want to select rows which have a minimum value of >= 5.  `apply` with `min` will find the minimum of each row, to use for the selection.  Note that the matrix used no longer matches the question.

```
> mat1[apply(mat1, 1, min) >= 5,,drop=FALSE]
  x y
c 7 8
```

For the edited question, using the average:

```
> mat[apply(mat, 1, mean) >= 5,,drop=FALSE]
  x  y
c 2 11
d 8  9
```

Comment: Instead of minimum, what about finding the average? I've changed "min" to "avg" and "average" with no luck 

edit: you beat me to it. Thank you!

Comment: Edited.  You want the function `mean`.